# $model-validation() always return false in yii?

Tags: php, validation, yii

i am new to YII framework. i am writing a simple method to change password, i am want to validate the controls like if blank then show the error message or if password and re-type password does not match then show error. i have used the below code to do this :

```
public function actionChange()
{
    $model=new Users;
    $model->scenario='change';
    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['Users']);                     

        if($model->validate())
            {
                print "true";   
            }
        else{

                print "false";  
            }   

        if($model->validate())
            {       
                $pass = md5($_POST['Users']['newPassword']);            
                $userModel = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
                $userModel->password = $pass; 
                $data = $userModel->update();
            }

            if(isset($data))
            {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',"Password changed successfully!");
                $this->redirect(array('Users/change'), true);
            }
        }


$this->render('change_password', array('model'=>$model,true));
}
```

But `**$model->validate()**` always returns false to me either i fill the fields or not.

**UPDATED:**

here is rule function :

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('is_active', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('first_name, joining_date,last_name, employee_code, username, password, role', 'required'),       
        array('employee_code', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('username','email'),      
        array('username','valid_username','on'=>array('create')),

        //array('username', 'contraints', 'readOnly'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),

        array('currentPassword, newPassword, newPasswordRepeat', 'required','on'=>array('change')),
        //array('newPassword', 'length', 'min' => 6, 'max'=>20, 'message'=>Yii::t("translation", "{attribute} is too short.")),
        //array('newPassword','ext.SPasswordValidator.SPasswordValidator', 'preset' => 'strong', 'max' => 41),
        array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'newPasswordRepeat','on'=>array('change')),
        array('currentPassword', 'equalPasswords','on'=>array('change')),
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on'=>array('forgotPassword')),
        array('joining_date', 'safe'),
        array('user_id, first_name, last_name, employee_code, username, password, role, joining_date, pending_regular_leave, pending_medical_leave, allocated_regular_leave, allocated_medical_leave, is_active', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}


public function equalPasswords($attribute, $params)
{
    $user = Users::findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    if ($user->password != md5($this->currentPassword))
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Old password is incorrect.');
}
```

please help me.

Comment: Show your validate function (as Jon noted below - it is not validate, but rules function) from model. It should contain validation rules that probably fails.

Comment: Not the validate function -- show the `rules()` function where your validation rules are defined. You can also `print_r($model->getErrors())` to see exactly what does not validate and why.

Comment: Maybe you've more rules than mandatory, like integer type... Show rules plz

Comment: @Jon... Yes, of course.

Comment: @Jon plese check my rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the correct method for setting the scenario you have two options:

```
$model=new Users('change');
```

or

```
$model=new Users;
$model->setScenario('change');
```

Also another issue is you aren't loading a model from the DB, unless you let them enter their user_id or whatever your primary key is on the form. Most likely you need to add this:

```
$model = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
//$model=new Users; //Should be removed
```

Otherwise it doesn't even know which record it is suppose to update in the DB plus all your other fields will be completely empty.

Also if you are using a form widget like CActiveForm you can also add this to your view and it will show you the messages from failed validations:

```
echo $form->errorSummary($model);
```

Answer (score 5):

For some reason your validation failes. Try to display validation error in else block (when validation fails).

```
 if($model->validate()) {
 ....
 }
 else {
      $errors = $model->getErrors();
      var_dump($errors); //or print_r($errors)
      exit;
 }
```

Another thing if it doesn't help, you can try to comment some validation rules from your rules and see what rule failes.